# Render video file into 3D

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

How can I render video like a normal wmv file into 3D so that I can translate, zoom or rotate the video based on the user's key down input? Is it possible?

Comment: how exactly would rotation work, if we take a video where the camera wasn't moving? What you wish to accomplish is very difficult, involves creating a 3d model from many 2d images.

Comment: The video is originally in 2D and I need to make it into a 3D and create a camera target on it..got any tutorial demostrate how to create a 3d model from 2d images? Thanks.

Comment: as I said, it is very difficult - meaning people are doing PhD's on this. After some searching i found a promising site:
http://www.i-programmer.info/news/105-artificial-intelligence/4917-free-library-converts-2d-image-to-3d.html

Comment: Is it convert into depth image? I am actually still a college student thou, By the way, I am actually want to do a program that similar to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2hxaijuZ6w..Translate and zoom the video based on the user's perspectives..I think I need to make the video into 3d before I can write to the screen..Am i correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, once again the link:

http://www.i-programmer.info/news/105-artificial-intelligence/4917-free-library-converts-2d-image-to-3d.html

It explains how the conversion works, and has a download libary link on the bottom. It converts a still 2 image or a video into a 3d depth image.